# PL/SQL Exceptions on Update/Delete of non-existing row

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am learning PL/SQL these days and currently working with Procedures and exceptions using oracle HR schema.

Here is my simple procedure.

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE DEL_JOB
(p_jobid jobs.job_id%TYPE)
AS 
sqle NUMBER; 
sqlm VARCHAR2(300);
BEGIN
DELETE FROM JOBS 
WHERE JOB_ID = UPPER(p_jobid);
IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No such record');
END IF;
EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
  sqle := SQLCODE;
  sqlm := SQLERRM;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('There is no job with this id that could be deleted');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error Code ='||sqle||' Error message =' ||sqlm);
END;
```

When I execute this procedure the output is

```
  No such record
  PL/SQL procedure successfully complete.
```

However, according to the Oracle PDF it should throw an exception and I should really get the message I entered in the exception.

Same thing happened with the Update on non existing record. 
Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe `SQL%NOTFOUND` returns `true` when no records are found. Your `IF` would evaluate to true in that case, and therefore write your put_line to terminal.  The SQL statement executed successfully. If you execute that SQL statement by itself from command line, you will receive 0 rows updated/deleted, not an Oracle error.

If you want to have an exception thrown, you could use `RAISE` inside your `IF` and point it to the exception in the exception block you want to have thrown.

Answer (score 12):

There is no "exception" - the sql executed successfully.  It successfully deleted every record that matched the criteria...which was 0 records.  Same thing if a similar update statement was executed.  You used the SQL%NOTFOUND to determine there were no records that were affected, but this does not mean there was an "exception".

Perhaps you're thinking of the NO_DATA_FOUND Exception raised if you try a "select into" clause and it doesn't find any matching records.

Comment: Yes I figured the same but "Oracle Database 11g Develop PL/SQL Program Units Vol1" pdf was stating there should be exception. Just wanted to confirm I am not missing anything, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

to do so you need to use

```
IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
    RAISE no_delete;
END IF;
```

and define your