# Oracle PLSQL exceptions for deletion procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to create a simple procedure that when passed a primary key will delete a record from a table.

I have read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841892/pl-sql-exceptions-on-update-delete-of-non-existing-row) about SQL%NOTFOUND.  I think that the solution for that problem is to use a function that checks that the parameter passed is a primary key of that table and returns a boolean.  I'm sure that there are more things to look out for here though.

What other problems or specific exceptions should I look for?

Here is the basic template for my procedure:

```
create or replace procedure delete_employee
  ( employee_id_i in employees.employee_id%type) is
begin
  if valid_employee(employee_id_i) then
    delete from employees where employee_id = employee_id_i;
  end if;
exception
  when others then
    log_error_proc(dbms_utility.format_error_stack(),
                   dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace());
end delete_employees;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `ROWCOUNT` attribute of the implicit cursor instead. This will return the number of affected rows from the `DELETE` statement, and saves you from having to query the table in your `valid_employee` function.

```
create or replace procedure delete_employee
  ( employee_id_i in employees.employee_id%type) is
begin
  delete from employees where employee_id = employee_id_i;
  if SQL%ROWCOUNT == 0 then
    null; -- throw exception, write log message, return something...
  end if;
exception
  when others then
    log_error_proc(dbms_utility.format_error_stack(),
                   dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace());
end delete_employees;
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Are there any other problems or exceptions to look for?

Comment: The only other problem would be if there was a referential integrity constraint on the primary key - this could cause a delete operation to throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks, that is a bit more useful.